# Using dependency injection how can I access a method in a class inside a service?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` 5.0.1 nuget package.

Here's the Dependency Injection service that I created:

```
public partial class BehaviorService : IBehaviorService
{
    public BehaviorService()
    {
    }

    public class MyClass : MyClassBase
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}

public interface IBehaviorService
{
}
```

As `MyClass` inherits from `MyClassBase`, I was thinking it was best to put that inside of a service—but I am very new to DI, so maybe it should be it's own service? I hope I can get advice here.

What I am not sure how to do is access the method inside the `MyClass` class that's inside of my `BehaviorService`, and how can I identify that in my interface?

***Note:*** To access the service, I was thinking to use something like:

```
var x = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BehaviorService>();
```

Comment: It may be more useful to start here: What problem were you hoping to solve by nesting the class? What led you to preferring this approach over, as you noted, a different service?

Comment: I perhaps don't need to nest the class.  Is there a way that I could make a MyClassService that inherites from MyClassBase and implements IMyClassService?  Do you feel that would be a good way to go.   Basically I just want to be able to make MyClass and only the MyMethod() available to parts of my application with a service but I am not sure how to do that as MyClassBase is a library class that I don't have access to.

Comment: It’s totally fine to register custom classes with your dependency injection container that derive from external classes that you don’t own—assuming, obviously, that those external classes are `public`. You just want to make sure your `MyClassService` implements a `IMyClassService`, as you propose, and code to that interface. And that interface should only return well-known types or abstractions—i.e., classes or interfaces that are in .NET, or made available by the project that your interface is defined within. I’ve included more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few conceptual problems here that you’re going to run into. I’m going to approach the problem from the outside in, eventually getting down to your specific question. The short answer to your immediate question, though, is that you either need to register and consume `MyClass` as its own service, or you need to instantiate and expose it from `BehaviorService`, and communicate that via your `IBehaviorService` interface. Before you get there, though, you’ll want to work through the broader conceptual problems discussed below.

#### Constructor Injection

Your dependencies should be passed into consuming class via the constructor, and wired up by your dependency injection container (i.e., the Microsoft dependency injection library). You should not call out to your dependency injection container from within your consuming class—by e.g. calling `GetRequiredService()`—as that just establishes a hard-coded dependency on your dependency injection container itself, while also obscuring the dependencies of your application from external callers.

> **Note:** Calling to your dependency injection container from within a consuming class is known as the *service locator pattern*, and it’s usually regarded as an anti-pattern.

#### Code to Interfaces

The dependency passed into your consuming class’s constructor should be your `IBehaviorService` interface, and that’s *all* your consuming class should ever be aware of. That means your consuming class has no awareness of implementation details that are *specific* to your concrete `BehaviorService` class unless they’re reflected in the `IBehaviorService` interface. This allows you to swap out implementations without maintaining a dependency on any one concrete implementation—which is the primary goal of dependency injection. Currently, your `IBehaviorService` contains no members, so there’s nothing consuming classes can do to interact with it.

> ***Note:*** Acknowledging that part of your question is *how* to expose your nested method via your interface—I’ll circle back to that below.

#### Accessing a Nested Class

There are three basic ways of accessing your nested `MyClass` class:

1. Establish an interface for it, register it with your dependency injection container, and inject it into a consuming class via the injector—i.e., to treat it exactly like an independent service.
2. Do the same as the above, but inject it into `BehaviorService` instead of your consuming class. That makes sense if `BehaviorService` relies on `MyClass`, but your consuming class doesn’t—which doesn’t sound like the case here.
3. Have your parent `BehaviorService` class create and expose an instance of `MyClass` via a member registered on the `IBehaviorService`. In this case, that member needs to be added to your `IBehaviorService` interface.

Of these, the first should be your preference unless `BehaviorService` depends on `MyClass`, in which case the second should be your preference. If *both* your consuming class *and* `BehaviorService` depend on `MyClass` then it should be injected into *both*. Finally, there are a *lot* of potential issues with the last option, so I’d avoid it; if you need to expose another class from a dependency, it should either be a well-known class (e.g., in the same project as your interface), or should adhere to an interface or base class which is.

#### Nested Classes vs. Services

Critically, in any of these cases, there is no real need or benefit to having `MyClass` nested; the same options are available if it were a separate class. From dependency injection’s perspective, it doesn’t really matter either way. So the question you should be asking yourself is what problem are you trying to solve by nesting it?

(Personally, I very rarely find cases where a nested classes are desirable—and especially `public` nested classes—but I don’t know your use case.)

#### Accessing *Just* a Nested Method

The above assumes you want to access the nested *class*. If you really only care about the *method* on the nested class, and only need it it context of your service, then the simpler approach is for your interface expose that method:

```cs
public interface IBehaviorService
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

And then have your `BehaviorService` proxy a request to an instance of the nested class:

```cs
public partial class BehaviorService : IBehaviorService
{

    private readonly MyClass myClass; 
   
    public BehaviorService()
    {
        myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    public void MyMethod() => myClass.MyMethod();

    private class MyClass : MyClassBase
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, neither your interface or your consumers need to be aware of the existence of the nested class—and, in fact, you might even be able to mark it as `private`. Your `BehaviorService` is effectively acting as a facade to the nested class. This works well if a) `MyClass` is really specific to your `BehaviorService` implementation, and/or b) you only need access to a couple of members of `MyClass`.

Comment: Aside, this is a really high-level summary of dependency injection, and glosses over a lot of nuance and caveats. If you _really_ want to understand the topic—and dramatically level-up your programming skills while you’re at it—I can’t recommend the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://www.amazon.com/dp/161729473X/) enough. I wrote a detailed review of it on Amazon. You probably don’t have time to put this project on hold to first read a lengthy technical book, but I’d definitely recommend returning to it if you are committed to writing loosely coupled code.

Comment: Great answer 